# Django Forms: Capture clicked value from template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a template which has a code like

```
<td><a href = "/os/">{{ contact.Tag_ID  }}</a></td>
```

to list the `Tag_ID` of items in a table. Now when I click on ot it goes to as `os` page which is a form with the Tag_ID field. I some how want to catch the `Tag_ID` when I click on it and pass it to the view ans set it as the initial value. I know how to set the initial value but cannot figure how to catch the `Tag_ID` or its associated data.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to pass the value in the url:

```
<td><a href = "/os/{{ contact.Tag_ID  }}">{{ contact.Tag_ID  }}</a></td>
```

or

```
<td><a href = "/os/?TagID={{ contact.Tag_ID  }}">{{ contact.Tag_ID  }}</a></td>
```

In the second case, it is just an old-style query string, which you can use javascript to read.  But, the better (django) way would be to use the first method, and do a pretty url.

In `urls.py`:

`(r'^os/(?P<tag_id>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/*', 'os_view_handler'),`

Then in `views.py`:

`def os_view_handler(request, tag_id=None):`

`...`

Comment: Yeah I had tried that, but couldn't figure out the url in the urls.py. Also how will I pass the Tag_ID it to my view.

Answer (score 1):

url code:

```
<a class="item" href="{% url "your_views_funct" contact.Tag_ID %}">{{ contact.Tag_ID }}</a>
```

and add this to your urls.py:

```
(r'^os/(?P<tag_id>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/*', 'your_views_funct'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your app, I'm guessing you want a URL like `/os/<ID>/`

First of all, you should declare this URL in your app's `url.py`. Second of all, use the `{% url %}` tag in the template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/ And thirdly, your view should be able to accept this ID as a parameter and act accordingly.